# ActionController::ParameterMissing in AuthController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting following error

```
param not found: customer
```

This is my auth_controller

```
def create
    @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
    if @customer.save
      flash[:success] = 'Success';
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Error'
    end
  end

  private
  def customer_params
    params.require(:customer).permit(:username,:email,:password)
  end
```

Here is my form

```
<%= form_for :customer, url: {action: :create} do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :username,placeholder: 'Username' %>
<%= f.password_field :password,placeholder: 'Password' %>
<%= f.email_field :email,placeholder: 'Email' %>
<input type="submit" value="Register" />
```

How do i resolve this error

Comment: Can you post the form being submitted? - You must have something like `form_for Customer.new do |f|`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you use the object of Customer class in form, either initialize @customer object in action before rendering form or use

**In action**

```
def action_name
  @customer = Customer.new
end
```

**And then, use this in form**

```
<%= form_for @customer, url: {action: :create} do |f| %>
```

**Or, initialize new object in form itself:**

```
<%= form_for Customer.new, url: {action: :create} do |f| %>
```

Comment: I am new to `rails`.I cant understand why my method is not working can you explain

Comment: have u tried any of the solution mentioned above. did it work for u

Comment: This is working fine `<%= form_for Customer.new, url: {action: :create} do |f| %>`

Comment: Shouldn't we try and answer the OP's question about why this isn't working? Passing `:customer` is a perfectly fine alternative to passing an instance of `Customer` per http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing an `:email` parameter, but it's not defined in your form. Your form has `:username` twice. Presumably you want `:email` for the field of type `email_field`.